# WARNING: terminal is not fully functional

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. But my terminal get to a bit probem sice two or three month ago. You know, when I want to see man page, git diff or something like that, I got a warning and I can't go up and down throw the results (e.g in man pages).
My terminal in those cases said "WARNING: terminal is not fully functional"!. I search about that and I try to fix it by exporting TERM variable, but it was not work for me.
Is there anyone that had a same problem or can say the solution?
Note: I don't know when and how I got in to the problem! :D

Answer (score 16):

It's likely your TERM setting is incorrect.
If you don't know what TERM should be set to, try `TERM=ansi` or `TERM=xterm-color`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I tried those, but unfortunately it didn't fix it!

Comment: what is the TERM setting in your .bash_profile or .profile?

Comment: TERM setting is "xterm", when I print the TERM by "echo $TERM" in my terminal.

Comment: Check that the TERM setting is exported. `export TERM=xterm` then do `man open` to check.

Comment: As I said before I check it by exporting something like that, but it is not work for me! BTW I export TERM again and test but it is not work!